# Equivalent of glColorMask in Metal for a kernel program?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, interop, metal

I am trying to move from OpenGL to Metal for my iOS apps. In my OpenGL code I use glColorMask (if I want to write only to selected channels, for example only to alpha channel of a texture) in many places.

In Metal, for render pipeline (though vertex and fragment shader) seems like MTLColorWriteMask is the equivalent of glColorMask. I can setup it up while creating a MTLRenderPipelineState through the MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor.

But I could not find a similar option for compute pipeline (through kernel function). I always need to write all the channels (red, green, blue and alpha) every time I write to an output texture. What if I want to preserve the alpha (or any other channel) and only want to modify the color channels? I can create a copy of the output texture and use it as one of the inputs and read alpha from it to preserve the values but that is expensive.

Comment: Instead of creating a duplicate texture and providing it as another input, seems like I can use the output texture in acess::read_write more and read alpha from it and write it back to output texture. That seems to work but not sure if that is always guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer memory architectures don't like writing only some bytes of data. A write to 1 out of 4 bytes usually involves reading those four bytes into the cache, modifying one of them in the cache, and then writing those four bytes back out into memory. Well, most computers read/write a *lot* more than 4 bytes at a time, but you get the idea.

This happens with framebuffers too. If you do a partial write mask, the hardware is still going to be doing the equivalent of a read/modify/write on that texture. It's just not changing all of the bytes its reads.

So you can do the same thing from your compute shader. Read the 4-vector value, modify the channels you want, and then write it back out. As long as the read and write are from the same shader invocation, there should be no synchronization problems (assuming that no other invocations are trying to read/write to that same location, but if that were the case, you'd have problems anyway).